# populate dropdown AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="companyId" style="height: 40px;" ng-options="id for id in companyId">
</select>
```

Hi.I have an array scope.companyId in controller which gets populated with the result of controller.array contains say [1,2,3].I need to populate this in dropdown.What is the mistake im doing?.

Thanks.

Comment: how looks your js code. is it possible to create a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: we would especially need to see your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ng-model to something else. Your array name and ng-model are same.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedId" style="height: 40px;" ng-options="id for id in companyId">
</select>
```

Since your ng-model and array (companyId) are same. After selecting a number, companyId will become variable not an array.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
$scope.companyId=[1,2,3,4];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedId" style="height: 40px;" ng-options="id for id in companyId">
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="companyIdModel" style="height: 40px;" ng-options="company_id as id for id in companyId">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set any item which should be pre-selected as value of select's ngModel

you try like this,

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

```
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.companyId = [1,2,3];
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets use this

```
<select ng-model="companyId" class="dropdown form-control input-sm"
                        ng-options="company as company for company in companyList"></select>
```

I suggest you to rename this $scope.companyId to $scope.companyList. or rename the binded model to your dropdown. Suggest you the following in js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.companyList= [1,2,3];
})
```

Here is the plnkr for you.
https://plnkr.co/edit/eNVKGeE0M92keNRDoQEE?p=preview